# How can I change the default browser using command line or registry in Windows 10 without admin rights?

Tags: windows-10, browser, default-settings

I am trying to find a way to change the default browser in Windows 10 from the command line or through a registry file. Is it possible?

My use-case is unique and specific to a project I am on.

I know I can do this with GPO but I need to find a way to do it without administrator rights.

Comment: "I need to find a way to do it without administrator rights." - If you have access to the registry editor that implies you have access to Administrator rights. Have your local Administrator change the default browser.

Comment: No. I can edit HKCU which doesn't need admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator rights for changing the default browser in Windows.

You could perhaps create a virtual machine, if Hyper-V/VMware/Virtualbox
is already installed on the computer, where you would be the administrator.

Comment: But I can change it from `Settings` > `Default apps` without needing administrator rights.